# pod install stuck on Installing GoogleUtilitiesComponents (1.1.0) indefinitely

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

When I try to 'pod install' it stuck in 'Installing GoogleUtilitiesComponents (1.1.0)'

[image]

When I tried with --verbose, it's stuck at this step.

Comment: I disconnected my vpn. Now it worked.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because trivial solution